# Powershell - Remove files inside the filtered folder

Tags: powershell, file, caching, filter, get-childitem

I'm trying to figure out how delete the files in multiple filtered folders from the Get-Childitem cmdlet.

What i want is find all folders with the name "Cache" in a specific path (Get-Childitem).
Then remove the files **inside** that Cache folder.

Powershell version:
5.1

The code below is not working probably, maybe bad wildcard choice etc.?

```
Get-ChildItem "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\" -recurse -Filter "Cache\*" | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname -WhatIf -recurse}
```

Hopefully someone can help me out, I'm kind of noob in this area :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging i found my solution.

Following code is working for me:

```
$base_dir = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA"
$name     = 'Cache'

Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.Name -eq $name
} | Select-Object -Expand FullName | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Item "$_\*" -Recurse -whatif
}
```

*(Remove -whatif, to remove the files)*

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `-Recurse` flag, you dont need to use `\` in your filter. Following filter will give you all items (including files and directories) that has the word cache in it (like bla**cache**bla)

```
Get-ChildItem $env:LOCALAPPDATA -recurse -Filter "*Cache*"
```

Or you can use `-ErrorAction` switch to silently continue when there is a failure to find all folders and files that has the name "cache".

```
Get-ChildItem $env:LOCALAPPDATA -recurse -Filter "Cache" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the explanation.

Using `-Filter "*Cache*"` is not what i need. I want exact the folders with the name Cache.

If I'm using `Get-ChildItem $env:LOCALAPPDATA -recurse -Filter "Cache" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $_.FullName }`

The output is for example:

```
C:\Users\xxx\xxxxx\Cache
C:\Users\x\xxxxx\Cache
C:\Users\xx\xxx\Cache
C:\Users\x\xxx\Acrobat\Cache
```

From there I want to remove the files and folders inside all folders with that name Cache, I just filtered from the `Get-ChildItem`

Example inside: C:\Users\x\xxx\Acrobat\Cache has files and folders like data_0, data_1, data_2, GPUCache(folder) etc. That I want to remove, but with every found cache folder (`foreach`)

Hopefully you understand my idea.

Thank you!